# SQLite string for replacing word with special characters

Tags: replace, sqlite

I am trying to replace a word that exists in a column in SQLite, but I am having some problems because it uses a special character.

following is the special character `'`, like "women's", "men's", shows up in SQLite like

```
Women&#39;s
Men&#39;s
```

So I tried the following string I normally use to make replacements under columns but failed

UPDATE SEARCHRESULT
SET CATEGORY = REPLACE(CATEGORY , 'Watches & Jewelry > Glasses > Women's Sunglasses', 'Watches & Jewelry > Glasses > Women's Sunglasses')

I would appreciate if someone can give me a working string for such a case since the string I am using is making the cells empty instead of replacing, normally this string works good with replacing cells that doesn’t have special characters.

Comment: Your UPDATE will simply replace the entire content of the matching categories with an empty space. Is that really what you intend? Or are you asking how to replace the single quote in the category with a space? "Normally this string works good" isn't very meaningful.

Comment: i did paste the wrong string, but i did find out that using the string here under would solve the problem

UPDATE SEARCHRESULT
SET CATEGORY = REPLACE(CATEGORY , '&#39;', '')

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using the following string solved my problem and removed that special charachter

UPDATE SEARCHRESULT
SET CATEGORY = REPLACE(CATEGORY , ''', '')